# What is the physical meaning of the components of a spin 1/2 spinor in matrix representation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors

If the spin operators for spin $1/2$ can be represented in matrix form using the Pauli Matrices,
e.g $S_x = \frac{1}{2}\hbar \sigma_x = \frac{1}{2}\hbar \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, What is the physical meaning of the components of a spinor in this matrix representation?

Comment: related/possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144294/50583 It might help if you expanded a bit on what sort of "meaning" you're looking for here

Comment: The eigenvectors of $S_x$ are treated differently by a magnetic field in the *x* direction in the [Zeeman effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect). One has a higher energy than the other, so corresponding energy levels are split. Is this the sort of thing that intrigues you?